# How to resolve window.chrome.runtime with webdriver

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I am getting **undefined** for window.chrome.runtime when open the chrome browser with selenium webdriver while on manually open the browser, we are getting object for window.chrome.runtime.

Is there any way to use Javascript's window.chrome.runtime with selenium webdriver?

I tried with following option but its didn't work for me.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\ChhaviSinghal\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data");  
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: Are you running Chrome as headless when it fails?

Comment: No, I am running Chrome with no headless. When we check window.chrome.runtime in Console on opening chrome window (automated) with Selenium Webdriver, we will get unidentified.                                                       Do we have any option to make our automatically browser open with this property have object and it will not return false